# Allow arbitrary properties in class Typescript types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've created a generic class in Typescript to extend objects starting from one passed in the constructor (through a Proxy, which will be returned in the constructor).

```js
class MyClass<T> {
    private _a: 5;
    constructor(source: T) {
        ...
        return new Proxy(Object.assign(this, source), { ... });
    }
}
```

If I want to instance `MyClass`, I'll do:

```js
interface DeepObject {
    a: number,
    b: {
         c: number,
         d: { ... }
    }
}

const x = new MyClass<DeepObject>({
    a: 1,
    b: {
        c: 2,
        d: { ... }
    }
});
```

So, as result, I will get x as a class that has inside "DeepObject" properties, like `a`, `b`, `b.d`. But if I try to access to `x.b.d`, it will obliviously not recognize the new properties as they get pushed inside in runtime at the current state.
Is there a way to use MyClass's `T` parameter as a class return type, knowing that I'm returning an edited "this" (MyClass + new props)?
I tried to set it to the constructor but typescript doesn't let me, like

```js
    constructor(source: T): ThisType<MyClass<T>> & T { ... }
    constructor(source: T): MyClass<T> & T { ... }
```

Moreover, using `//@ts-ignore` in multiple lines (like

```js
//@ts-ignore
x.b.c = 5;
//@ts-ignore
x.b.d.f = 9;
```

), is a misusage of typescript features, IMHO.

The same is to put `[key: string]: any` inside the class, above or below the properties.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly charge the return type of the constructor. You can however use the same approach as `Proxy` usses and have a separate declaration for the constructor which does use the generic type parameter in the return

```
class _MyClass<T> {
    private _a: 5;
    constructor(source: T) {

        return new Proxy(Object.assign(this, source), { ... });
    }
}

interface DeepObject {
    a: number,
    b: {
        c: number,
        d: {  }
    }
}
const MyClass : {
    new<T> (s:T) : _MyClass<T> & T
} = _MyClass as any
const x = new MyClass<DeepObject>({
    a: 1,
    b: {
        c: 2,
        d: {  }
    }
});

x.b.c
```

Comment: Whoa! That's great! Thank you very much!
But why do you cast "_MyClass as any"?

Comment: @AlexanderCerutti because technically speaking it does not return the type `MyClass` declares it does. So we use a hammer to make it fit 

Comment: Oh, well... I understand now. I tried to remove it and saw. Typescript is weird sometimes. Again, thanks a lot!