# class Thing<T> extends T

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

Regarding the title, is something equivalent to `class Thing<T> extends T` possible in typescript? Preferably in a way that's readable. Currently trying this line of code results in the error `Cannot find name 'T'` in VSCode. Tried finding an answer on here and google, but found nothing similar.

Comment: Can you explain in greater depth the use-case of this?

Comment: Sure. I'm writing tests for a variety of classes. In-case I'd like to change the behavior of any of those classes, or if they're abstract, I make a TestClass kind of object that extends the class needing to be tested. I would like to have a central construct such as this so if I had to, say, decorate all of my test objects with additional functionality, I'd only have to write that code in one place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow arbitrary properties in class Typescript types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736855/allow-arbitrary-properties-in-class-typescript-types)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly, you can crete an intermediary class and then use a type assertion to get it to fit with a custom constructor signature that returns `T` and the class:

```
class _Thing { }

const Thing: {
  new <T>(): _Thing & T
} = _Thing as any;


new Thing<{ prop: string }>().prop
```

Answer (score 0):

`T` is a type, only values (classes) can be extended:

```
function <T extends new(...arg:any[]) => any> Mixin(Parent: T) {
  return class Mixin extends Parent {
    // ...
  }
}

const Sub = Mixin(class Parent {
 works() { /*..*/ }
 //...
});

(new Sub).works();
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, actually. VSCode threw an error on `extends Parent` saying `T is not a constructor function type`. But changing `T` to `T extends new(...arg:any[]) => any` fixed it for me.

Comment: @anthony aaah right, I'm afk so I couldn't test it, great that you could fix it :)

Comment: But it doesn't work for abstract parents :(. What a shame. So close!

Comment: @anthony what do you mean by "abstract" ? I guess you are looking for union types then ...

Comment: That the Parent's type can also be abstract in my code. Apparently this is a known issue `https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5843`. Unfortunately it's not a clean issue to be able to say "extendable but not constructable".