# TypeScript - Allowing arbitrary extensions to class instance

Tags: javascript, typescript

Using TypeScript, I'd like to create a class instances of which have a number of methods, but can be initialized to automatically add several other methods, based off of one of the predefined ones. The base class has a `props` method, which takes an object, and does stuff with it:

```js
class MyClass {
  props(props: Record<string, any>) {
    // Do something with passed props 
  }
}
```

I want to be able to pass in a list of method names on construction that are then used to dynamically add class instance methods which *use* this `props` method to do something. So:

```js
  constructor(propList: Array<string> = []) {
    propList.forEach(propName => {
      // Don't allow overwriting of existing methods
      if (this[propName]) {
        throw new Error(
          `Cannot create prop setter for '${propName}'. Method with that name already exists!`
        );
      } else {
        this[propName] = (value: any) => {
          this.props({ [propName]: value });
        };
      }
    });
  }
```

When I try to do so, TS shows an error:

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'MyClass'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'MyClass'.ts(7053)`

Is there a way to do this? Saw this [semi-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736855/allow-arbitrary-properties-in-class-typescript-types), but didn't feel applicable. Thanks! New to TS.

**EDIT**

I tried having the class implement an open interface:

```js
interface CanBeExtended {
  [key: string]: any;
}

class MyClass implements CanBeExtended {
  // ...
```

but I think that is making the class itself, but not instances of the class, extensible. At any rate, it is not fixing the issue.

Comment: This should probably be a function that you can call i.e. `class Child extends Parent(...) {`, but it's unsafe anyways because you could accidentally override a built-in or inherited method D:

Comment: "that is [not] making instances of the class, extensible" No, it makes a `CanBeExtended` extensible, which wprls if you widen a `MyClass` instance to `CanBeExtended` (e.g., `const x: CanBeExtended = new MyClass([])`).  An `implements` class is just a check, it doesn't affect the typing.  If you want `MyClass` instances to be treated like that you can put an index signature in the class itself, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoDBMw).  This *might* be what you want, but this is almost like turning off type safety within `MyClass` completely.  Seems like what you're asking for, though. ‍♂️

Comment: That's great @jcalz. This use case is within a component-library, and only applies to an internal tool, so type safety doesn't need to be airtight. Works like a charm. If you add that as an answer, I'd love to select it.

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance.  Aside: I just read my previous comment, and "wprls" is supposed to be "works" which I guess means my right hand was not properly placed on the keyboard, or maybe something short-circuited in my brain.  Oh well, to err is hrmxn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [declare an index signature in a `class`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#index-signatures), as long as it doesn't conflict with the types any other members (so if you have a `props()` method, you can't make the index signature `[k: string]: number`, for example, since `props` is a method and not a `number`).  In your case you want to use [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), which will definitely not conflict (although it's also not very type safe).  So it looks like this:

```
class MyClass {
  
  [k: string]: any; // index signature
  
  constructor(propList: Array<string> = []) {
    propList.forEach(propName => {
      // Don't allow overwriting of existing methods
      if (this[propName]) { // no error here anymore
        throw new Error(
          `Cannot create prop setter for '${propName}'. Method with that name already exists!`
        );
      } else {
        this[propName] = (value: any) => { // no error here anymore
          this.props({ [propName]: value });
        };
      }
    });
  }
  props(props: Record<string, any>) {
    // Do something with passed props 
  }

}
```

And your errors go away.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1pegbQGsAuaCAFwCcBLAOwHMBdEsG+AbmgHpPpaATAKYAPUlTo0wZAK4UBuXMAD2NchSnAyiigAoADhUW6AMlXIkAghQph4AHlW06APmgBefAwCU6XNn2GTcgA6ADMtAFEwYAALPQNdADkwAFsBNxdMbCyuHgARZQByMmgwEBBFAHdoRQA3AQoK6jJHapDoYVNm+mhUsmjFPghfLKo27T7TPH9ElIEvH2zsvoMqmgEq8KstbWHF6AADRBYaRWLgWUk06dIBMjJ66DCKaAKAEjRppNSAXwKguFu-T40AqVD60D6kmgElSJRAFz48HaQk6EAAhPtdllPGwsd92iAIGlMnsIdFJp9Zgw3NBtDVSlIBMxWN5XBksUtyRAgtMINo0PhKakmNB6SBGdBvjiOZLcXtvsMpXLJbheXFDBASAAlARKCh8eyURwAGhKrCc3hJ2G40HypEUvXJ3VB4N0kCJwN5OGwCow3yAA)

Comment: Maybe use a generic parameter instead of `string` for the keys

Comment: [argh, you can't](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)… would've been too easy

Comment: @Bergi yeah there are definitely other approaches... but this is the answer to the question as asked.  I suppose I could go into more detail about why an index signature with `any` isn't necessarily something people want to do in general

Comment: @jcalz - Is there some method of having the key be a generic type (eg, one of the elements of propList), rather than just `string`? Attempting to improve on this, I ran into the same issue as @Bergi did in the comment above